# Hive dropping the count of the record

Tags: sql, hive, mapreduce, hiveql, data-warehouse

I created a hive table from a CSV

```sql
CREATE TABLE RECORD_CSV(
  completed_on string, distance_travelled double, 
  end_location_lat double, end_location_long double, 
  started_on string, driver_rating double, 
  rider_rating double, start_zip_code int, 
  end_zip_code int, charity_id int, 
  requested_car_category string, free_credit_used double, 
  surge_factor double, start_location_long double, 
  start_location_lat double, color string, 
  make string, model string, year int, 
  rating double, Date string, PRCP double, 
  TMAX double, TMIN double, AWND double, 
  GustSpeed2 double, Fog double, HeavyFog double, 
  Thunder double
) 
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

When i run
`SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RECORD_CSV;` it returns

```
OK
911057
Time taken: 21.403 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

When I create a another table partitioned by `color` field by using the below command
The count of the row drops.

```sql
CREATE TABLE RECORD_CSV_BYCOLOR(completed_on string, distance_travelled double,
end_location_lat double ,end_location_long double,
started_on string ,driver_rating double ,rider_rating double ,
start_zip_code int ,end_zip_code int ,charity_id int,
requested_car_category string,free_credit_used double,
surge_factor double,start_location_long double,start_location_lat double ,
make string ,model string ,year int ,rating double,Date string,PRCP double,
TMAX double,TMIN double,AWND double,GustSpeed2 double,
Fog double,HeavyFog double,Thunder double
)
PARTITIONED BY (color string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS
TERMINATED BY ',' 
STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

```sql
INSERT OVERWRITE table RECORD_CSV_BYCOLOR PARTITION(color) 
select completed_on, distance_travelled,end_location_lat, 
end_location_long, started_on, driver_rating, rider_rating,
start_zip_code, end_zip_code, charity_id, requested_car_category,
free_credit_used, surge_factor, start_location_long, start_location_lat,
make, model, year, rating, Date, PRCP, TMAX, TMIN, AWND, GustSpeed2,
Fog, HeavyFog, Thunder, color FROM RECORD_CSV;
```

When i run `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM RECORD_CSV_BYCOLOR;` I see that the record has dropped

```
OK
693991
Time taken: 21.552 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

Below is the difference by `color` using `GROUP BY` for table `RECORD_CSV`

```
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 3   Cumulative CPU: 7.11 sec   HDFS Read: 165793766 HDFS Write: 349 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 7 seconds 110 msec
OK
 Silver 634
Black   204004
Bronze  214
Burgundy    1587
GREEN   195
Gold    6346
Gray    644
Maroon  847
Silver  170241
Silver  147
Tan 1066
Teal    913
White   152919
White   404
Yellow/Gold 20540
Blue    90
Brown   18594
Gray    134155
Navy Blue   48
Red 80352
WHITE   52
Yellow  448
Black   361
Blue    81999
Dark Blue   199
Dark Grey   18
Green   15396
Grey    12503
Magenta 324
Orange  5817
Time taken: 25.186 seconds, Fetched: 30 row(s)
```

and the below for `RECORD_CSV_BYCOLOR`

```
MapReduce Jobs Launched: 
Stage-Stage-1: Map: 1  Reduce: 1   Cumulative CPU: 3.48 sec   HDFS Read: 30648230 HDFS Write: 281 SUCCESS
Total MapReduce CPU Time Spent: 3 seconds 480 msec
OK
 Silver 634
Black   361
Blue    90
Bronze  214
Brown   18594
Burgundy    1587
Dark Blue   199
Dark Grey   18
GREEN   195
Gold    6346
Gray    644
Green   15396
Grey    12503
Magenta 324
Maroon  847
Navy Blue   48
Orange  5817
Red 80352
Silver  147
Tan 1066
Teal    913
WHITE   52
White   404
Yellow  448
Yellow/Gold 20540
Time taken: 20.937 seconds, Fetched: 25 row(s)
```

The `GROUP BY` in the source table gives count for same color twice, and the target table picks up the row with least count. The difference seems to be there, but why is that even happening? What code should i change?

Comment: After investigation i found that 
`select color, count() from weather where color = 'Black' group by color` - gives 204004 
and 
`select color, count() from weather where color = 'Black ' group by color` - gives 361 There is a whitespace in the color, but why the partition is not made with `'Black'` & `'Black '`

Comment: In your INSERT OVERWRITE ... SELECT, use `TRIM(color)` to consolidate all variations into a single partition.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for.